# Is there a method to distribute new registered customers to existing employees in the database by order in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I designed this laravel app for a business where customers can register on the website and employees can manage them from the backoffice,I want this management to be automatically fair, which means that each time a customer appears in the database, he will be assigned to the first employee, if tomorrow another customer shows up,he will be assigned to the second employee,...
is there a way to do this task? i heard that laravel Scheduling is similar to what i want but how can i keep track of the last employee that been affected a client? so each employee can get same amount of clients , and not only the first one gets to have them all.

Comment: Assign newly added customer to employee where `emp_id = cust_id % count(employees)`. This is not exactly a laravel solution but this should solve your use case in a practical way with basically no overheads.

Comment: @vish4071 the problem with this solution is that the employees id isn't in order : i mean the list of employees id isn't = [1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,...] its more like  [1, 7 ,13 ,25 ,...] so the result of this math equation could result with an emp_id that isn't really an employee you got me?

Comment: In that case, I have 2 questions...1. Why is that like that? `id` should normally be auto-increment and 2. Even if these are missing, are they random? Because if they are random, this would still work practically.

Comment: @vish4071 yes the id is auto-increment, they are like that beacause i have one table of users, and the user could be a client , a general admin,assistant admin, or an entry clerk, so the columns adding isn't in order a clinet can be entered and then a new  employee could come after, also if you add an employee and delete it after the id wil be skipped it wont be in order again (wich is annoying actually i wish the id will be in order in case of deletation)

Comment: oops. I missed the point that id skip was from employees and not from customers. As long as customers have ordered auto-increment id, there should be no problem. Say, the designation of emp is `RM` (relationship manager). You can always fetch the current count as `select count(id) from employee where designation=RM`. Then, you can do `n = cust_id % count`, and use this number to assign it to respective RM. eg. `select id from employee where designation=RM order by id limit 1 offset n`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `assigned_at` column and store the time that customer was assinged to employee. Now you can find last employee by sorting by `assinged_at` column. To find next employee you can sort employees by `id` and find next employee after this one.

Comment: @Mohammed yeah that seems like a solution but not optimal right? like i want to avoid adding a new column or table , i was wondering if there is some kind of package or technlogie that handles these stuff, but thanks for the idea it is actually a solution

Comment: As i know laravel scheduling doesn't provide you what you want. I didn't find any specific package for that. But if you have redis in your stack, you can store last assignment info in redis. It depends on what aspects of this process is important to you